# Are there any programs that create fonts with minor imperfections?

Tags: font

I've been thinking: wouldn't it be cool to write a book using a font that has minor imperfections? For example, when you handwrite, say, the letter E multiple times over, each preceding E won't look exactly the same. They won't be carbon copies.

Are there any programs that offer font packs like this, or would one need to be created?

Comment: I'm not sure if asking for fonts is considered on-topic here (see: [Would icon and font library questions be on topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185)). SR deals with *software* – so asking for fonts (or icons, images, etc) IMHO doesn't fit here.